# Sequelize Many-to-Many relationship but only create if exists

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

**Objective:**

Create a hashtagging system against a `Product`

**Models:**

- `Products`
- `Hashtags`
- `ProductTags` (join table)

**What I'm doing**

When I create a new product the following happens:

1. Product is created
2. Hashtag is created
3. ProductTag join is created

The `data` looks like this:

```json
{
  "category_id":2,
  "description":"Some description",
  "price": 45,
  "currency_id": "GBP",
  "hashtags":[
    {"tag":"tagnumber1"}, 
    {"tag":"tagnumber2"}, 
    {"tag":"tagnumber3"}
  ]
}
```

The `Product.create` code looks like this:

```js
models.Product.create(data, {
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Hashtag,
          as: "hashtags",
          attributes: models.Hashtag.fields
        }
      ]
    });
```

**Issue**

When I create the product for the first time with tag: `tagnumber1`, `tagnumber2`,`tagnumber3`. It adds these into the Hashtag table and creates the relation in the `ProductTag` table.

But when I create another product with the same tag: `tagnumber1`, `tagnumber2`,`tagnumber3`. It still adds these same tags into the Hashtag table.

**How?**

Is it possible on the second add to still have it `INSERT` into `ProductTags` but instead of duplicating the tags in Hashtag to grab the `ids` if they match?

[image: Tables]